# How to send protractor report to different emails generated using protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I am using `protractor-html-screenshot-reporter` for report generation through protractor. It is providing me the html report.

But how can I send the report to different email ID's as attachment to my other team members?

Or is there any other plugin of protractor for email report generation?

Answer (score 0):

It is not something I would solve on the `protractor` side. Delegate the task to your Continuous Integration server, e.g. `jenkins` or `Bamboo` or smth else.

Generate something your CI can understand - a test report in `JUnit XML` format with the help of `JUnitXmlReporter` from [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters) and configure your CI to send an email(s) when your tests fail.